# How to get a answer?

Tags: discussion

Is there any way by which I can attract more people to my question so that I can get the answer?

This is the question asked by me

[How to compare magnetic moment of chromium(III) and cobalt(II) ions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152855/how-to-compare-magnetic-moment-of-chromiumiii-and-cobaltii-ions)

Even after putting it on bounty I am not able to get a answer.I have seen people getting more than 200 views on their question. So if I can get a way so that more and more people see my question so that hopefully I get a satisfactory answer. Is it possible?

Comment: In general, no; the bounty is the only *site-specific* mechanism to draw attention. You can of course start posting your question in chat, etc. But make sure to do that politely and not in a spammy way. View count is basically a lottery; it's not usually possible, nor is it a good idea, to aim for that. High view count does not correlate with question quality.

Comment: Sometimes you can "improve" your question by providing additional detail and clarifications, including your own efforts (which might provide leads to a solution if you are stuck). Some questions are ignored for lack of detail or clarity, or because they suggest a lack of effort. Posting a bounty does not necessarily circumvent such problems. (I can't comment much more on your particular question).

Comment: We try to answer as much questions as possible but ultimately we are humans. There is a limit to our knowledge. It is not expected that every questions can be answered. If that happens then we would be settling in Mars right now. With that being said, if your question can be answered than someone would have answered by now. Bounties do attract attention but that doesn't guarantee that your question will be answered.